# Need something like alias in insert table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a value into a table. However that value comes from that table too. And I want to check if there is a duplicate key on that table. Since this value come from that table too, the query says that a column name is ambiguous.

```
$result2 = "INSERT INTO estock_saldo 
                (items, customer_id, quantity , reference_no, size)                 
            SELECT  
                items, '".$member_id."', '".$quantity[$i]."', reference_no, size                            
            FROM    
                estock_saldo
            WHERE   id in ({$order_id[$i]})
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
            UPDATE estock_saldo.quantity = estock_saldo.quantity - '".$quantity[$i]."'";

            $res2 = $mysqli->query($result2);   
            if(!$res2){ printf("Errormessage 2: %s\n", $mysqli->error); die(); }
```

The ambiguous come from `estock_saldo.quantity`. I have tried to alias the column name. However you can't do that in insert table.

Answer (score 1):

Problem persist in the below shown code snippet. You can't use column alias in `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO estock_saldo 
                (items, customer_id, quantity AS asquan
                                       <-- HERE
```

What you are trying will always have a duplicate entry, since you are inserting the same record again. Instead of `INSERT` statement, you actually meant to do a `UPDATE` like

```
UPDATE estock_saldo SET 
quantity = quantity - '".$quantity[$i]."'"
WHERE   id in ({$order_id[$i]});
```

Comment: That's where the ambiguous start. I am trying to alias the column name.

Comment: No you can't; you should supply the exact column name. Refer MySQL doc for more information.

Comment: That's why I need a solution beside alias. Can you figure it out, please?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are intended to do but see edit if that helps.

Comment: Column 'quantity' in field list is still ambiguous

Comment: You don't need a insert statement actually rather try performing a UPDATE.

Comment: I need an insert statement before updating the row, and find the duplicate key. :/